# Accessing nested data from parent

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm unable to make head or tail of the [Nested selctions](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) or at least to adapt the information to my needs.

I have some JSON data here which is formatted like this:

```
{
  'name': 'root'
  'children': [
    {
      'name': 'child1'
    },
    {
      'name': 'child2'
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to display the child data within my root node. Let's just assume I have something like this:

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
      .text(d.name)
```

So at this point my event handler is the data from root. How can I access the data of the child objects from there, so that my above code would display something like "root (child1, child2)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var childNames = d.children.map(function(child) {
  return child.name;
});

nodeEnter
  .append("text")
  .text(d.name + ' (' + childNames.join(', ') + ')');
```

Comment: But d.children just returns the children _object_. I need the string from name within every child.

Comment: Finally this was the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

The code to display what you want would be something like this (using nested selections).

```
var top = d3.selectAll("div").data(data).enter().append("div");
top.append("div").text(function(d) { return d.name; });
// nested selection here
top.selectAll("div.child").data(function(d) { return d.children; })
   .enter().append("div").attr("class", "child")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
```

Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DLMd7/).

Comment: Looks promising. I tried to adapt it to my code which is based on the [cluster dendrogram](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063570): `var node = svg.selectAll("g.node").data(nodes).enter().append("g").attr("class", "node").attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });
node.append("text").attr("class", "data").text("")
node.selectAll(".data").data( function(d) { return d.children; }).enter().append("text").attr("class", "match").text( function(d) { return d.name; } );` But now I always get _Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined_ at .data()